# Sculpting tools don’t work

Tags: sculpting, tools

[image]None of the tools seems to have any effect on the object , all the tools seems block … i use a graphic tablet ….I been trying everything . I stay at this point whit subdivisions . I change the brush …  radius. Strength … nothing…closed. Uninstalled . Find. Drivers for the tablet  appears whit all the tools

Any ideas ?
Thks so muxh

Comment: Not enough details. At least post an image of your screen. (You can edit your question and drag and drop the image straight into the question.) The usual problem for beginners to sculpting though is that the mesh isn't subdivided enough to give the tools asnything to work with.

Comment: hello could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/